# Python xgettext merges gettext and ngettext strings, breaking translation lookup

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext, extract

Running:

```
> xgettext test.py -o out.pot
```

On the Python snippet test.py:

```
def main(num):
    gettext("TEST")
    ngettext(num, "TEST", "TESTS")
```

Produces a pot file with the following row (translated strings are in the po file):

```
#: test.py:3 test.py:4
msgid "TEST"
msgid_plural "TESTS"
msgstr[0] "TEST-SINGLE"
msgstr[1] "TEST-PLURAL"
```

After turning this into a po file and then a mo file. I cannot get translations for gettest("TEST") calls.

```
> ngettext("TEST", "TESTS", 1)
> TEST-SINGLE
> gettext("TEST")
> TEST
```

I am using the standard gettext package for Python. I am not sure if these merging behaviour is expected, but it seems to destroy the ability to look up translations for for non pluralized strings. Is there a way to avoid this?

I was thinking of hacking up a fallback for gettext, to try a ngettext call if the first one fails. That seems very hacky though.

Comment: [removed this, cause I figured out how to answer my own question]

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem in a recent project. In my opinion, this might be considered as a bug in the python gettext module. And others share this opinion since there is [an open issue for this](https://bugs.python.org/issue18319) on Python bugtracker, since 2013... I proposed [a patch](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/19869) but it may take a while until it is included in a release.

Using `ngettext("TEST", "TESTS", 1)` instead of `ngettext("TEST")` is a pretty simple workaroud of course. Not completely satisfactory, but it works...

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to stem from the way that the gettext package looks up translations. For gettext and ugettext calls, it simply looks inside the catalog for _catalog['TEST'], and does not search for _catalog[("TEST", 0)].

I do not believe this to be the correct behaviour since xgettext decides to merge the two strings, but I cannot find anything in the documentation to prove one way or the other.

To solve this, I am monkey patching in two replacement methods for gettext and ugettext, that will fallback on a (message, 0) catalog lookup if the simple lookup fails.

Comment: When I run xgettext test.py -o test.pot. I get the following result:

Answer (score 1):

The two entries are exactly the same i.e. singular entry is the same as your plural one.  To demonstrate:

```
msgid "Test"
msgstr "Toets"

msgid "Test"
msgid_plural "Tests"
msgstr[0] "Toets"
msgstr[1] "Toetse"
```

Then use msgfmt to compile it:

```
msgfmt test.po 
bob.po:4: duplicate message definition...
bob.po:2: ...this is the location of the first definition
msgfmt: found 1 fatal error
```

Gettext uses the msgid as the key for your string so it will see these singular and plural strings are duplicates.

Comment: When I run xgettext test.py -o test.pot. I get the following result:
    #: test.py:25 test.py:26
    msgid "TEST"
    msgid_plural "TESTS"
    msgstr[0] ""
    msgstr[1] "

Comment: This would suggest to me that gettext intends them to be merged. It is not very userfriendly if you have to update every single gettext("test") if you decide to add a ngettext("test", "tests", num) call into your program.

Comment: It intends them to be merged because they, to Gettext are exactly the same, as I said above.  To disambiguate them, and to be honest you probably need that for your translators, you need to use pgettext which will provide a msgctxt entry that allows disambiguation.  The lookup key is then "msgctxt+msgid" and that will make these entries unique.